# How can I get a list of entities from existing data with ServiceStack.OrmLite?

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack, tooling

I am using test data to run integration tests. So I am using the following method

```
public static IEnumerable<ProductPhase> GetProductPhases()
{
    return new List<ProductPhase>
    {
        new ProductPhase { Id = "FirstPhase", Order = 1 },
        new ProductPhase { Id = "SecondPhase", Order = 2 },
        new ProductPhase { Id = "ThirdPhase", Order = 3 }, // ...
    }
}

[Test]
public void MyTest()
{
    using (var db = HostContext.TryResolve<IDbConnectionFactory>.OpenDbConnection())
    {
        db.DeleteAll<ProductPhase>();
        db.InsertAll(GetProductPhases());
    }

    // Do test stuff ...
}
```

To validate completely my integration tests I need to be synchronized with data which is inserted in production. This data can contain dozens of lines and each time I need to refactor `GetProductPhases()` method manually, so I am near the *reality*.

What I am looking for is a method to select existing SQL data to something that I can copy paste to `ProductPhase` object initializer.

So, the ability to call something like:

```
db.Select<ProductPhase>().DumpList() // where db is connected to production server, so I can get actual values and it returns a string with new List<ProductPhase> { new ProductPhase { Id = "FirstPhase", Order = 1 }, new ProductPhase { Id = "SecondPhase", Order = 2 }, new ProductPhase { Id = "ThirdPhase", Order = 3 }, // ... }
```

Maybe there is a better method to do that, I don't know, I am open to alternatives.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would save the results to CSV with `.ToCsv()` extension method than deserialize it before the test starts. Typically I'd save the CSV in an external `.csv` file (that's set to copy to output folder) so its easy to update.

Comment: That's a brilliant idea. So I can use SSMS 'export to csv' feature to directly save it overwriting existing csv.

Comment: @labilbe For consistency I would use the same serializer to serialize/deserialize the CSV, just have a test that you can run to re-generate all the .csv's.